# How to position absolutely inside float:left?

Tags: css, html, css-float, css-position

Why adding of left rule changes behavior so drastically? Is it possible to position relative to default position?

http://jsfiddle.net/suzancioc/drDn3/6/

HTML:

```
    <div class='level0'>
   <div class='level1'>
       Hello

   </div>
   <div class='level1'>
       Hello
       <div id='inner2'>inner2</div>
   </div>
       <div class='level1'>
       Hello
       <div id='inner3'>inner3</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.level0 {
   height:40px;
   width: 500px;
   background:red;
}
.level1 {
   float:left;
   margin:2px;
   border-style: solid;
   background: cyan;

}
#inner1 {
   position: absolute;
   background: green;
}

#inner2 {
   position: absolute;
   background: green;
    left:0px;
}

#inner3 {
   position: absolute;
   background: green;
}
```

Comment: This jsFiddle shows the difference between `float:left;` on your `level1` and having `float:none;`. http://jsfiddle.net/drDn3/11/

Answer (score 12):

In order to position absolute something you need to assign that div(in your case) to a relative positioned parent

```
.level1 {
   float:left;
   margin:2px;
   border-style: solid;
   background: cyan;
   position:relative;

}
```

Adding `position:relative` makes `.level1` a sort of coordinate system for all elements inside of it.

Take a look at [**this JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/drDn3/9/)